# How to make an edge/vertices follow path?

Tags: vertices, edges, path, 2d

I got along much further, but now I have another problem. I created quite sharp curves with the arrays and the planes that are passing through mostly follow along quite good, but sometimes these planes cross lines they should not cross. Seems like they sometimes do not respect the commands that they been given to, when the curves of the arrays become sharp.What I mean is shown in the screenshot I added. Does anyone know how to solve the problem/ make the planes do not cross the arrays? Thanks! [image]

Problem solved!
The problem was that I positioned my animation along the y axis while you have been doing it on the x axis. I just had to change the shrinkwrap modifier on both sides to y and then I got it! Took me so long to find this little change in the settings to get there. Thank you Duarte Farrajota Ramos, Markus von Broady and Chris for taking your time! God bless!

[image]Im trying to animate 2D abstract art. I would like to know if there is the possibility or maybe an addon that enables the edge or the vertices of an object to follow a path? Or if there is another solution that solves the problem I just have been confronted with?

To be more detailed which problem im trying to solve please check out the two pictures I posted to describe what I am trying to do in blender. My basic idea is to let several planes move side by side, so that the edges are being bend and deformed exactly the same way while thouching each other at the exact same spot. For one single plane this would be easily solved with the "lattice" modifier moving along a path I think, but this addon doent enable you to bend an edge of another plane while the edge of the plane selected is being bend.

The first picture shows 3 planes in 2D. Below there are 4 paths.
In the second picture you see the planes move the way I just described.

I also would like to know if there is the possibility to join or pair the corner vertices of the edges, so that the planes move at the same speed and no plane gets "ahead" of the other during the animation. So that the horizontal edges of all planes make one horizontal line, if you know what I mean.

I would be super grateful if you could provide a solution to the problem!
Thank you for your time!

[image: animate the edges of several planes along path]

---

[image]

Plane shrinkwraps randomly to the bezier curve.

---

[image]

Plane shrinkwraps randomly to the bezier curve.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Create a number of desired bezier curve objects with the intended shapes.

[image]

For each of them add a small plane object, make sure it is aligned with the starting point of the bezier curve. For ease of setup, the curve origin should ideally be set to the first vertex of the curve.

[image]

To each plane add an *Array* modifier, set the array to *Fit Curve*.

Then add a *Curve* modifier, set it to deform along each corresponding bezier curve. In the illustrated setup along the Y axis.

[image]

These steps are necessary because you can't shrink-wrap directly to a bezier curve object.

In between each curve create the (soon to-be) deformed planes. Enter *Edit Mode* on them, create two *Vertex Groups*, `Left` and `Right` and assign to them the corresponding left and right vertex.

[image]

Now for each plane add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier set to *Simple*, followed by two *Shrinkwrap* modifiers.

[image]

For each *Shrinkwrap* modifier set the target to the plane objects created in the first step that stand correspondingly to the left and right of each plane. Set *Wrap Method* to *Project* on the X axis, and limit it to the `Left` and `Right` vertex group.

Repeat for every deforming plane object that you have, selecting the corresponding bezier planes.

If you now move the planes along the curve they will deform as desired.

[image]

Comment: Nice. Very similar to the solution I was putting together - you beat me to it with a much nicer way of building the curves than I was coming up with :-D Very nicely presented too!

Comment: Thanks Rich. I was initially trying with multiple curve modifiers and vertex groups, but failed miserably. The setup was pain to get working reliably with more than one curve.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking time to help me! Your response was so quick and detailed, really amazing!

The animation of yours is really what Im looking for, I came further, but still not there unfortunately. 

I think I copied every step you did. I have the same settings in the modifiers, but the plane seems to shrinkwrap randomly. As I move the plane towards the right bezier curve it randomly shrinkwraps that one.

Comment: @Dadaram make sure both modifiers are set to *Project* mode. Also turn on both *Positive* and *Negative* axis influence, so that if the plane overshoots the curves it still works.

Answer (score 3):

Another geonodes setup:

[image]

As a side effect of how it's done, it works also in 3D:

[image]

[image]

It works for multiple splines in the curve object, but it requires the user to correctly arrange the splines (it doesn't sort the splines by their $y$ coordinate, but it could be done). Also since the question is tagged 2D, I didn't add anything extra to e.g. interpolate the $z$-bends nicely.

Answer (score 1):

here is a geometry nodes solution:

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

adding new splines is easy as that:

[image]

--- update

my resolution wasn't good, so here i improved my setup by resolution:

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]